# CartoDB: Can't find where to change Google Drive log in credentials

Tags: carto

I'm trying to create a new table in CartoDB.

1. I click New Table
2. I click the Google Drive data tab
3. I click the connect with gdrive button
4. At this point it seems to be automatically logging in to the wrong Google Drive account.

Is there a way to reset that so I can get into the right account?

I'm trying to marry up my table with a Google spreadsheet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently we don't have a way to manually revoke datasource oauths from GDrive or Dropbox from the Web Mapping Tool, but we do detect when the user has remotely revoked access to a service.

So what you can do is revoke the permission/access from your Google Account and then grant access to the correct acc.:

> Account -> Security -> Account Permissions -> View All -> "Connect
>   your Google Drive data with CartoDB" -> "Revoke Access" button

For example, I have it here (your URL might vary if you're logged in with multiple accounts):
https://security.google.com/settings/u/0/security/permissions?hl=en

Hope it helps!